# SQL when insert in stored procedure results in error "incorrect syntax near '='"

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Stored procedure code (I just cut the other codes)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_v2]
    @CashCountBatchNo INT,
    @CashierID VARCHAR(10),
    @Remarks   VARCHAR(50),
    @CashCount NVARCHAR(1000),
    @ADJ       NVARCHAR(1000) = '',
    @CutOff    VARCHAR(8) = ''
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @tbl TABLE(DENOMINATION MONEY, [COUNT] INT)                
    DECLARE @tblADJ TABLE(Description VARCHAR(300), Amount MONEY)                
    DECLARE @Totals TABLE(CC MONEY, CH MONEY, CASHTOCOLLECT MONEY)

    SET @CashCount = REPLACE(@CashCount, '_S_', ' Select ')                
    SET @CashCount = REPLACE(@CashCount, '_;', ' union all ')                
    SET @CashCount = SUBSTRING(@CashCount, 0, LEN(@CashCount) - 8) 

    INSERT INTO @tbl(DENOMINATION, [COUNT])
         EXEC sp_executesql @CashCount

    SELECT * FROM @tbl
    RETURN
```

It just created successfully, now my problem...

```
UERMHIMS..Usp_Cashier_SaveCashCount_v2 
'',
'',
'',
'DENOMINATION=1000, COUNT=1 union select DENOMINATION=500, COUNT=1',
'',
''
```

At this point on the 4 parameters are needed for the stored procedure, and when I execute the stored procedure, it throws an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: The names of the procedures don't match. Assuming they were supposed to be the same, weren't you supposed to either include `_S_` as a marker in the parameter? Either way your dynamic SQL is missing `select` at the beginning.

Comment: They are the same procedure, my fault I changed the other one. What should I change?, to match the required SP fields with the input parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much for that insight, Now I understand what you've said, and my input parameters are now working.

Comment: We don't know what you're trying to do. All we know is that you're passing a string that isn't *close* to being an actual query into the stored procedure, doing some transformations on it (including lopping off the last 8 characters based on some unstated assumption) and then trying to run it as a query. If you want us to help, please explain *what you're trying to achieve*. Probably help to add some table definitions and sample data, too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print out the variable `@CashCount` before executing the statement.

From what I could tell of your logic, the contents of `@CashCount` would be something like:

```
DENOMINATION=1000, COUNT=1 union select DENOMINATION=500,
```

And this isn't valid SQL.

As a test, I run this SQL in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/17207), and get exactly the same error.

Comment: I don't get it, what do you mean? Sorry I'm just new in this field.

Comment: @Alphatrix . . . I don't know how to explain it otherwise.